# Linear stochastic programming/easy formulas

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables, linear-programming, stochastic-programming

I have a question about some stochastic linear programming formulas, namely
(4.3),(4.4),(4.5) and (4,6) in the snippet below.
I do not follow how was created the argument of $c$ in (4.3), the formula (4.4)
and from (4.4) the formula (4.5), and finally (4.6).
I'm looking on it almost a week without any success.

The snippet is taken from the book *Introduction to stochastic programming* by
John Birge,the second edition.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My reputation it too low to add a comment, so don't take this as an answer rather than comment.

What exactly is your problem?

Those (4.3-4.5) are just assumptions/pre-conditions to give a real sounding problem/illstration. And those assumptions are summarized into the optimization problem (4.6).
c is a new variable introduced which is (later) used for optimization purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. My problem is how $\frac{w\cdot \pi \cdot x^2}{4}$ was created. And also both sides of the inequality $\frac{w}{\xi^3}\leq 39.27$ was created. And finally $\frac{w^3}{\xi^4}\leq 63,169$ and $Q(w,x,\xi)$. Just as I've said in my OQ, all the (,)'s. **Are they all just ilustration examples with no rule** ? Is $c$ a variable or rather a function in (4.3) ?